# Difference between effect and useSignalEffect in signals-react

Tags: reactjs, signals, preact

This question is not an issue, it is for educational purpose.

I was trying out effect and useSignalEffect from @preact/signals-react in react application.
Problem is i see effect and useSignalEffect have same behaviour they both run when the subscribed signal changes.
Could anybody clearify on whats the difference between them.

Example I have used:-

```
import React from 'react'
import {effect,  useSignal,useSignalEffect } from '@preact/signals-react'


export default function ComputedSignalExample() {
    const count = useSignal(0);

    useSignalEffect(() => {
      console.log(`From useSignalEffect: ${count}`); 
    });

    effect(() => {
        console.log(`From Effect: ${count}`); 
    });
  
    return (
      <div>
        <p>The current count is: {count}</p>
        <button onClick={() => count.value++}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

`From Effect: 0 From useSignalEffect: 0 From Effect: 1 From useSignalEffect: 1 From Effect: 2 From useSignalEffect: 2`

I used useSignalEffect with a dependency array, to see if it might have same setup as useEffect react hook, but seems like, it doesn't care about dependency array.
`useSignalEffect(() => {`
`console.log(From useSignalEffect);`
`},[count]);`
Also tried this, but no effect
`useSignalEffect(() => {`
`console.log(From useSignalEffect);`
`},[count.value]);`

Answer (score 0):

The docs explicitly state what this is for:

> If you need to instantiate new signals or create new side effects on signal changes inside your components, you can use the `useSignal`, `useComputed` and `useSignalEffect` hooks.

https://github.com/preactjs/signals/tree/main/packages/react#hooks

Don't use `effect` in components, it will be recreated (and resubscribe) upon every single rerender of your component. For a `console.log()`, this won't have much of an impact, but heavier effects could.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is in scope. You would use effect() when you create a side effect that can be used anywhere in your project, but you would use useSignalEffect() when you want to create an effect specific specifically limited to within the component.

Comment: The wording here is borderline incorrect. An effect is not "limited to within the component" when you use `useSignalEffect()`; this just creates a stable subscription (effect) instead of recreating on every render.